# Bash style pattern matching, expansion and pathname parsing for Java

Tags: java, regex, expression

My project has objects structured in a tree and needs to implement wild card and pattern matching, path expansion for accessing the said objects. This functionality is very similar to what Bash does with its command line.

A sample query might be

`find .\[NC]*\Hospitals\Addresses\*`

This would recursively search all nodes below the current one for the Addresses of all hospitals that are located in the states which name starts with N or C (ie Nevada, Nebraska, California, etc).

Are there any existing and **fairly lightweight** libraries or frameworks for **Java** to do this? I dont want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the option to use Java 7, it has glob built in: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileOps.html

If not, this StackOverflow question & answers may prove useful: [Is there an equivalent of java.util.regex for "glob" type patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247772/is-there-an-equivalent-of-java-util-regex-for-glob-type-patterns)