# Pattern searching

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I want to implement pattern ' * ' text matching on java. What is the simplest way to do this?
Is Pattern.java the best solution for this?

Comment: Please show us some examples demonstrating what it is *exactly* that you're looking to do.

Comment: matching what?  strings?  filenames?  And what is the syntax?  regex?  glob?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look into the regular expression package `java.util.regex`. You find a good starting point [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to match the text occurring between two single quotes in a string. The regex for this is `'.*'` and not `'*'`. Code for this will look like this

```
String input = "abcd'efg'hij";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("'.*'").matcher(input); //initializes a matcher
System.out.println("Found ? " + matcher.find() + 
                   "\nFound what ? "+ matcher.group()); //prints 'efg'
```

In case you want to match `'*'` literally then use the regex `'\\*'` (escape `*` with a `\`)

Check out documentation on `java.util.regex.Pattern` and  `java.util.regex.Matcher` classes.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built in glob-matcher for Java, but you can easily [convert a glob to a regex and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247772/is-there-an-equivalent-of-java-util-regex-for-glob-type-patterns) use a regex library.

Comment: Java 7 does have a builtin glob-matcher. See [FileSystem.getPathMatcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher(java.lang.String))

Comment: neat; although it has special meanings with path boundaries and things