# Java Regex: Need to find expressions that include '[' character

Tags: java, regex

How do I write a Java regular expression that will find the character '[' or ']' in the expression?  Since these are special characters in regular expressions, I'm stumped.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134558/java-regex-list-of-all-special-characters-that-needs-to-be-escaped-in-regex

Comment: You need to escape it using \. Try `[\[\]]`

Comment: You escape them. `\\[` `\\]`. Please read [Regex: Special Characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)

Comment: http://ideone.com/ySMBqk

Comment: @AntonH  I had read through both of these and neither have helped me, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @hwnd I had read through both of these and neither have helped me, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below regex to match the literal `[`,`]` symbols,

```
"[\\[\\]]"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gU2iR4/1)

Comment: My comment points out this related answer.

Comment: op needs to put the above inside a char class.

Answer (score 0):

Other than escaping, as that can get a little confusing I *suppose*, you can use the hex values of the characters:

```
[ = 5B
] = 5D

\x5B // For use in your expression
```