# Java regular expression get 2 strings before and after a certain word in string

Tags: java, regex

For example I have this text and email:

```
String text ="For move information please contact us: contact@gmail.com, ask Peter to help."
String email="contact@gmail.com";
```

I want to get two 10 chars sized strings as a result, one from the left side of email, other from the right. **Result I want to see**: *Left*-ntact us: *Right*:, ask Pete

Right now **matcher.find()** in while loop returns **false**. And as a result both **leftContext** and **rightContext** are null.

Here is my code:

```
String email = "contact@gmail.com";
int nLeft = 5;
int nRight = 5;
String leftContext;
String rightContext;

String wordDelRegEx = "[^а-яА-Яa-zA-Z0-9.-]+?";
        String leftRegEx = "(\\w{" + nLeft + "})";
        String rightRegEx = "(\\w{" + nRight + "})";

        //matches something like: aaaaaaa email@gmail.com bbbbbbbbbb
        String contextRe = leftRegEx + wordDelRegEx +email + wordDelRegEx + rightRegEx;

        String h ="For move information please contact us: contact@gmail.com, ask Peter to help."
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(contextRe);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(h);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            leftContext = matcher.group(1);
            rightContext = matcher.group(2);
        }

        System.out.println("Left: " + leftContext);
        System.out.println("Right: " + rightContext);
```

Comment: It fails in this particular case because you're searching for "email@gmail.com" but your sample string has "contact@gmail.com".

Comment: Sorry, my fault. It is not the reason, I edited question.

Comment: Also, your question has examples where you want space and `:` in the result, but your `leftRegEx` and `rightRegEx` patterns won't allow that because space and `:` won't match `\\w`.

Comment: Additionaly, you have to escape the `.` in `èmail`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134558/java-regex-list-of-all-special-characters-that-needs-to-be-escaped-in-regex

Comment: I tried to change it, but no effect: 
String leftRegEx = "(.{" + nLeft + "})";
String rightRegEx = "(.{" + nRight + "})";

Comment: @Smutje, I tried email = "support@dou\\Q.\\Eua"; still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following as your string contains **colon (:), comma(,) and spaces (\s):**

There is no Use of wordDelRegEx variable:

```
String leftRegEx = "([\\w\\s,:]{" + nLeft + "})";

String rightRegEx = "([\\w\\s,:]{" + nRight + "})";
```

//matches something like: aaaaaaa email@gmail.com bbbbbbbbbb

```
String contextRe =leftRegEx+ email +rightRegEx;
```

Comment: You helped me a lot + email should look like this: email = "email@gmail\\Q.\\Ecom";

Comment: Actually email is the variable name that you used in the above mentioned code.