# How to split String with special character using Java

Tags: java, regex

What is the way, how to split String with special character using Java?

I have **very simple captcha** like this:

**5 + 10**

```
String captcha = "5 + 10";
String[] captchaSplit = captcha.split("+");
```

And I get error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
>   Dangling meta character '+' near index 0

How to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Regex, List of all special characters that needs to be escaped in regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134558/java-regex-list-of-all-special-characters-that-needs-to-be-escaped-in-regex)

Comment: You probably want to split on `" *[+] *"` to trim the targets of spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` is a reserved character in regular expression and [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) takes `regExp` as a parameter. You can escape it by `\\+` which will now match `+`.

Answer (score 3):

Type it in square brackets

```
String captcha = "5 + 10";
String[] captchaSplit = captcha.split("[+]");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to split String with multiple special symbols/characters, it's more convenient to use Guava library that contains **Splitter** class:

```
    @Test
    public void testSplitter() {
        String str = "1***2***3";
        List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList(Splitter.on("***").split(str));
        Assert.assertThat(list.size(), is(3));
    }
```