# Why the method String.split() split the string that have the "|" in unexpected way

Tags: string, split

When I want to split the String "aaaa|bbbbb|123456" with the method String.split("|"), the result is  unexpected .

My code:

```
String s = "aaaa|bbbbb|123456";
String[] temp = s.split("|");
for (String str:temp) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

But the result is:

```
a
a
a
a
|
b
b
b
b
b
|
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

are there anything special with char "|" ?

Comment: Try with String.split('|').

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting a Java String by the pipe symbol using split("|")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796160/splitting-a-java-string-by-the-pipe-symbol-using-split)

Answer (score 1):

In Java the following characters has to be escaped in regular expressions

> .[]{}()*+-?^$|

You could either escape the `|` character during split like

```
string.split("\\|");
```

You could also achieve the same using `StringTokenizer` as follows

String test = "abc.def.123";

```
StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(test, "|");

while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
    System.out.println(token.nextToken());
}
```

To know more about the list of characters that has to be escaped with regex pattern look [at this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134558/list-of-all-special-characters-that-need-to-be-escaped-in-a-regex)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the pipe:

```
String[] temp = s.split("\\|");
```

The pipe symbol `|` has a special meaning in regex, used to indicate an alternation.  Your original code resulted in splits happening between every character, which isn't what you want.

Comment: I realized there is an exact duplicate only after I posted initially, hence I could not close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use escape sequences,

```
String s="aaaa|bbbbb|123456";
String [] temp=s.split("\\|");
for(String str:temp) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Sting split(String regex) method wants a regular expression as its parameter.It splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

A preceding backslash ("\") turns a metachacter into a literal character. Because this is also the Java escape character in strings, you need to use "\" to present the backslash character. To split a string with a literal '|' character in Java,

```
you must use split("\\|")
```

. For example,

```
String s="aaaa|bbbbb|123456";
String [] temp=s.split("\\|");
for(String str:temp) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

[For more detals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

[Summary of regular-expression constructs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum)