# Is there any need to escape the slash('/') character for regular expressions in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code snippet:

```
Pattern patternOfSlashContainingBackSlash=Pattern.compile("\\/");
Pattern patternOfSlashNotContainingBackSlash=Pattern.compile("/");

String slash = "/";

Matcher matcherOfSlashContainingBackSlash = patternOfSlashContainingBackSlash.matcher(slash);
Matcher matcherOfSlashNotContainingBackSlash = patternOfSlashNotContainingBackSlash.matcher(slash);

//both patterns match the slash
System.out.println(matcherOfSlashContainingBackSlash.matches());
System.out.println(matcherOfSlashNotContainingBackSlash.matches());
```

My questions:

1. What is the difference (from Java perspective) between the two patterns, or is there any difference?
2. Is the '/' character just a plain character for regex(not a special character like ']' is) ,from Java perspective?

The java version on which I run this is 1.8

This question is different from the others, since it makes it clear that the patterns "\\/" and "/" are the same for Java programming language.

Thank you very much!

Comment: As far as I know, it wont make much of a difference. Putting the escape slash in front of a character ussually means that the character has to be taken as the literal character... unless it has some special meaning. In the case of the literal, where the slash would be optional, it would not be necessary... IntelliJ also says it is a redundant character escape.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of all special characters that need to be escaped in a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134558/list-of-all-special-characters-that-need-to-be-escaped-in-a-regex)

Comment: @radoh , I do not think this question is duplicated since it also clarifies the fact that there is no difference  between "\\/" and "/" patterns.Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/` is not special in Java regex, it is in JavaScript where we have syntax `/regex/flags`. Java allows escaping characters even if they don't require it, probably to make such regex more portable. So `Pattern.compile("\\/")` and `Pattern.compile("/")` will behave the same.

BTW `]` by itself is not special character. If it is not part of `[...]` construct you don't need to escape it, but you are allowed to (at least in Java, I am not sure about other regex flavors).

Answer (score 4):

`/` is not a special character in Java regexes. `"\\/"` is equivalent to `"/"`.

Answer (score 3):

The forward slash `/` character is not a command character in Java `Pattern` representations (nor in normal `String`s), and does not require escaping.

The **back-slash** character `\` requires escaping in Java `String`s, as it is used to encode special sequences such as newline (`"\n"`).

E.g. `String singleBackslash = "\\";`

As the back-slash is *also* used to signify special constructs in Java `Pattern` representations, it may require double escaping in `Pattern` definitions.

E.g. `Pattern singleBackSlash = Pattern.compile("\\\\");`

See [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for examples of `Pattern` constructs involving the back-slash.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to escape the slash character. The reference for Java's regex syntax is the Javadoc for class [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). There, it lists all the characters that have special meaning. The slash is not present in that list.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the reason why people escape the `/` character is that they come from different regex flavours (like Javascript) where you can define a pattern enclosing it between two slashes and if you want to match one slash you need to escape it.

```
var pattern = /\d\/\d/; // Valid pattern of 2 digits divided by a slash, which must be escaped.
```

From a Java perspective, though,it is equivalent and thus there's no need to escape it.