# How do I get the last substring starting with +,-,*,/?

Tags: java, algorithm

If I have expression in a string variable like this `20+567-321`, so how can I extract last number `321` from it where operator can be `+`,`-`,`*`,`/`

If the string expression is just `321`, I have to get `321`, here there is no operator in the expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by splitting your string based on your operators as following:

```
String[] result = myString.split("[-+*/]");
```

`[+|-|*|/]` is Regex that specifies the points from where your string should be split.  Here, `result[result.length-1]`  is your required string.

**EDIT**
As suggested by @ElliotFrisch we need to escape `-` in regex while specifying it.  So following pattern should also work:

```
String[] result = myString.split("[+|\\-|*|/]");
```

Here is the list of characters they need to be escaped.

[Link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134558/list-of-all-special-characters-that-need-to-be-escaped-in-a-regex)

Comment: I needed `String[] result = myString.split("[+|-|*|/]");`

Comment: for  negative sign it is returning incorrect results - for example "87-1" the result is 87-1, but result should be 1

Comment: @raxx Make sure you are using the same character for `-`. You are probably using different characters in the expression and in your code.

Comment: @raxx please check now. I've updated the answer. I've tested it and it's working. Here is the link where I've tested it. `jdoodle.com/a/7uQ`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch as per your suggestion your pattern should work in `87-1` but it is giving the same output. Any reasons?

Comment: Interesting; `String[] result = myString.split("[+|\\-|*|/]");` works.

Comment: Okay so we have to escape `-` here.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be an assignment for learning programming and algo, and also I doubt splitting using Regex would be efficient in a case where only last substring is required.

1. Start from end, and iterate until the *length of the string* times.
2. Declare a empty string say *Result*
3. While looping, if any of those operator is found, return *Result*, else **prepend** the traversed character to the string *Result*.
4. Return *Result*

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] output = s.split("[+-/*]");
String ans = output[output.length-1];
```

Assumption here that there will be no spaces and the string contains only numbers and arithmetic operators.

`[+-/*]` is a regular expression that matches only the characters we provide inside the square brackets. We are splitting based on those characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna do it with StringTokenizer:

```
 public static void main(String args[])

{
   String expression = "20+567-321";
   StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(expression, "+-*/");
   int count = tokenizer.countTokens();
   if( count > 0){
       for(int i=0; i< count; i++){
           if(i == count - 1 ){
               System.out.println(tokenizer.nextToken());
           }else{
               tokenizer.nextToken();
           }
       }
   } 
}
```

Recall you can specify multiple delimiters in StringTokenizer.