# Result separation with regex

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I wrote a parser that reads a file line by line and parses it with a regex statement. (Regex below)

```
case "countries":
            pattern = "\\\"(.+?)\\\"(\\s+)?(\\((.+?)\\))?(\\s+)?(\\{(.+?)\\(\\#(.+?)\\)\\})?(\\s+)?(.+)";
            substitution = "$1, $4, $7, $8, $10";
            break;
```

This outputs a list with all the groups I want and each group separated by a comma. (through the result.split(",");)
Now lets say I don't want to use a comma but instead an | or an *. Changing the comma to any other string doesn't seem to change anything. What am I missing?

```
try (CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(myLocalPath + "CSV/" + choice.toLowerCase() + ".csv")))
{
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    while (br.readLine() != null)
    {
        String nextLine = br.readLine();

        Matcher matcher = r.matcher(nextLine);

        String result = matcher.replaceAll(substitution);

        String[] line = result.split("lorem");

        csvWriter.writeNext(line, false);
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
    System.out.println("Parsing done!");
}
```

Comment: Try escaping `\\|` and `\\*` because both are meta-characters in regex.

Comment: Escaping the character didnt work (java should escape characters immediately regardless if it detects its regex right?)

Comment: Does your input consistently have that pattern ? Your provided input as `lorem`. What exactly is your input ? Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134558/list-of-all-special-characters-that-need-to-be-escaped-in-a-regex) answer.

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Cv4tPE/1

Comment: You meant the regex by 'an example' right? @MauricePerry

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma an example of input file

Comment: Yes the list you see in the regex link is a short part of the input file

Answer (score 0):

seems what you're missing is [`Pattern.quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)), if argument must be read literally, indeed split argument is a regex.

```
String[] line = result.split(Pattern.quote("..."));
```

Comment: Cool, i didnt know about the Pattern.quote part. Really neat to know however i dont think this is usefull for my application since my regex statement already performed as it should. Im already getting the results i want and in the groups i want. I just want to change the comma that gets added between each seperator to any other character. Still gonna look more at Pattern.quote though!

Comment: about the choice of separator, in a csv it is generally `,` or `;` however if this caracter can appear in a field it must be escaped, commonly within enclosing quotes, it may be changed in CSVWriter settings