# how to find the presence of particular characters in the word entered

Tags: android

- i have an edit text, in which the name is entered. When i click the
  button it should do a check.
- the check should be like, the word contains any characters $ [ ] . #
  +

when i used regex

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[$. #+]");
 else if(regex.matcher(name).find()) {
                showDialog(this, "invalid");
            }
```

i was not able to give [] check is their any other way to check the    existence of  $ [ ] . # +  characters.

Comment: then it shows illegal escape character in  Pattern.compile("[$. #+]"); @Ken Y-N

Comment: Oops, I meant double-escape `"\\[\\$\\. #\\+\\]"` - I think that's right...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of all special characters that need to be escaped in a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134558/list-of-all-special-characters-that-need-to-be-escaped-in-a-regex)