# How to split a string if my string contains ^ symbol in java. I want to create an array out of it

Tags: java

I have a string, which contains ^ symbol given below.

**String tempName = "afds^afcu^e200f.pdf"**

I want to split it like below

**[afds, afcu, e200f]**

How to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter to [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) is a regular expression, which has special meta-characters. If the delimiter you're splitting on contains those special characters (e.g. `^`), you have two options:

- Escape the characters using `\`, which has to be doubled in a Java string literal to `\\`:

  ```java
  String[] result = tempName.split("\\^");
  ```
- If you don't want to bother with that, or if the delimiter is dynamically assigned at runtime, so you can't escape the special characters yourself, call [`Pattern.quote()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) to do it for you:

  ```java
  String[] result = tempName.split(Pattern.quote("^"));
  ```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `\\` in `split` method of `String` to split the string by this (`^`), because `^` is an special character in regular expression and you need to omit it with `\\`:

```
String tempName = "afds^afcu^e200f.pdf";
String [] result = tempName.split("\\^");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

> Java characters that have to be escaped in regular expressions are:
> **.[]{}()<>*+-=!?^$|**

> Two of the closing brackets (] and }) are only need to be escaped after opening the same type of bracket.
> In []-brackets some characters (like + and -) do sometimes work without escape.

[more info...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134558/list-of-all-special-characters-that-need-to-be-escaped-in-a-regex)

Answer (score 0):

`String.split()` in Java takes a regular expression. Since `^` is a control character in regex (when at the beginning of the regex string it means "the start of the line"), we need to escape it with a backslash. Since backslash is a control character in Java string literals, we also need to escape *that* with another backslash.

```
String tempName = "afds^afcu^e200f.pdf";
String[] parts = tempName.split("\\^");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the retrieve a substring without the file extension and split that according to the delimiter that is required (^). This is shown below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String tempName = "afds^afcu^e200f.pdf";
        String withoutFileFormat = tempName.substring(0, tempName.length() - 4); //retrieve the string without the file format
        String[] splitArray = withoutFileFormat.split("\\^"); //split it using the "^", use escape characters
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitArray)); //output the result
       
    }
```

Required Output:

```
[afds, afcu, e200f]
```