# java.util.regex matching parentheses

Tags: java, regex, string

I am using java.util.regex for matching like bellow

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input = "<b>I love you (LT): </b>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    String patternStr =  "I love you (LT):";
    String noParentStr =  "I love you";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
    Pattern noParentPattern =  Pattern.compile(noParentStr);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    Matcher noParrentTheseMatcher = noParentPattern.matcher(input);

    System.out.println("result:" + matcher.find());
    System.out.println("result no parenthese:" + noParrentTheseMatcher.find());
}
```

I can see the `input` string contain `patternStr` "I love you (LT):". But I get the result

```
result:false
result no parenthese:true
```

How can i match string contain parentheses '(',')'

Comment: do you need regular expression? None of the given examples require regular expressions. `input.contains(patternStr)`

Answer (score 2):

In regex, parentheses are meta characters.
i.e., they are reserved for special use.
Specifically a feature called "Capture Groups".

Try escaping them with a `\` before each bracket

`I love you \(LT\):`

[List of all special characters that need to be escaped in a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134558/list-of-all-special-characters-that-need-to-be-escaped-in-a-regex)

Comment: It looks like you might as well just use `Pattern.quote` for this.

Answer (score 2):

As it has been pointed out in the comments, you don't need to use a regex to check if your input `String` contains `I love you (LT):`. In fact, there is no actual pattern to represent, only a character by character comparison between a portion of your input and the string you're looking for.

To achieve what you want, you could use the `contains` method of the `String` class, which suits perfectly your needs.

```
String input = "<b>I love you (LT): </b>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
String strToLookFor = "I love you (LT):";
System.out.println("Result w Contains: " + input.contains(strToLookFor));  //Returns true
```

Instead, if you actually need to use a regex because it is a requirement. Then, as @Yarin already said, you need to escape the parenthesis since those are characters with a special meaning. They're in fact employed for capturing groups.

```
String input = "<b>I love you (LT): </b>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
String strToLookFor = "I love you (LT):";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(strPattern);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

System.out.println("Result w Pattern: " + matcher.find());  //Returns true
```