# Regex for finding only single alphabets in a string and ignore consecutive double

Tags: java, regex, string, duplicates

I have searched a lot but I am unable to find a regex that could select only single alphabets and double them while those alphabets which are already double, should remain untouched.

I tried

```
String str = "yahoo";
str = str.replaceAll("(\\w)\\1+", "$0$0");
```

But since this `(\\w)\\1+` selects all double elements, my output becomes `yahoooo`. I tried to add negation to it `!(\\w)\\1+` but didn't work and output becomes same as input. I have tried

```
str.replaceAll(".", "$0$0");
```

But that doubles every character including which are already doubled.

Please help to write an `regex` that could replace all single character with double while double character should remain untouched.

## Example

```
abc -> aabbcc
yahoo -> yyaahhoo (o should remain untouched)
opinion -> ooppiinniioonn
aaaaaabc -> aaaaaabbcc
```

Comment: What's the desired outcome for `aaa` ?

Comment: @bobblebubble it should remain untouched i.e. the output should be `aaa`

Comment: It's what the second solution in my answer does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match using this regex:

```bash
((.)\2+)|(.)
```

And replace it with:

```
$1$3$3
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/u1tgka/5)

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `((.)\2+)`: Match a character and capture in group #2 and using `\2+` next to it to make sure we match all multiple repeats of captured character. Capture all the repeated characters in group #1
- `|`: OR
- `(.)`: Match any character and capture in group #3

[**Code Demo:**](https://ideone.com/IhRZ20)

```
import java.util.List;
 
class Ideone {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> input = List.of("aaa", "abc", "yahoo",
                "opinion", "aaaaaabc");
 
        for (String s: input) {
            System.out.println( s + " => " +
                  s.replaceAll("((.)\\2+)|(.)", "$1$3$3") );
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```bash
aaa => aaa
abc => aabbcc
yahoo => yyaahhoo
opinion => ooppiinniioonn
aaaaaabc => aaaaaabbcc
```

Comment: Leave `aaa` untouchd? Not sure... :) Good idea however.

Comment: OP wrote: `those alphabets which are already double, should remain untouched` so first `aa` remains untouched but last `a` is not double hence it becomes `aa` making it `aaaa`

Comment: Yes, sorry. I think you are right :) Already upvoted. I'm confused a bit about this.

Comment: @Eatsamulhaq: If you want `aaa` to not become `aaaa` then check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

The solution by @anubhava, if viable in Java, is probably the best way to go.  For a more brute force approach, we can try a regex iteration approach on the following pattern:

```
(\\w)\\1+|\\w
```

This matches, eagerly, a series of similar letters (two or more of them), followed by, that failing, a single letter.  For each match, we can no-op on the multi-letter match, and double up any other single letter.  Here is a short Java code which does this:

```java
List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"abc", "yahoo", "opinion", "aaaaaabc"});
String pattern = "(\\w)\\1+|\\w";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

for (String input : inputs) {
    Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        if (m.group().matches("(\\w)\\1+")) {
            m.appendReplacement(buffer, m.group());
            }
            else {
                m.appendReplacement(buffer, m.group() + m.group());
            }
        }
        m.appendTail(buffer);
        System.out.println(input + " => " + buffer.toString());
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
abc => aabbcc
yahoo => yyaahhoo
opinion => ooppiinniioonn
aaaaaabc => aaaaaabbcc
```

Answer (score 2):

I've got two different understandings of the question.

1. If the goal is to get an even amount of each word character:
   Search for `(\w)\1?` and replace with `$1$1` ([regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/99Vobg/1)).
2. If just solely characters should be duplicated and others left untouched:
   Search for `(\w)\1?(\1*)` and replace with `$1$1$2` ([regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/k5Ffzy/1)).

[Captures](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) a [word character `\w`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) to `$1`, [optionally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) [matches the same character again](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html). The second variant captures any more of the same character to `$2` for attaching in the replacement.

FYI: If using as a Java string remember to [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134558/list-of-all-special-characters-that-need-to-be-escaped-in-a-regex) the pattern. E.g. `\1` -> `\\1`, `\w` ->`\\w`, ...

Comment: That is also nifty, matching the optional backreferenc to `\1` in group 2 so it can not be evautated anymore :-)  I was playing around with lookarounds, but that would just complicate things https://regex101.com/r/yz1hGy/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thank you! I'm still unsure about the exact requirements, so I put two options. First I thought only of the second variant. Maybe it clears up, let's see :)