# Regex Pattern in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression as defined

> `AAA_BBB_CCCC_(.*)_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]T[0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9]`.

There is a string defined as --> `**AAA_BBB_CCCC_DDD_EEEE_19710101T123456**` and in the code, we have matcher.group(1) which can filter out what is desired as (DDD_EEEE). Now, I've a new string coming in as --> `**AAA_BBB_ATCCCC_DDD_EEEE_19710101T123456**`. Is there a way that I can change the regex to satisfy both old and new string? I tried few solutions that came up from Stackoverflow questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520566/regular-expression-wildcard-matching) and others but that didn't work quite right for me.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/Mx9pCx/1, just add `(?:AT)?` before `CCCC`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Worked like a charm. Can you please add it as answer so that I can accept it.?

Comment: You might also consider using `[0-9]{8}T[0-9]{6}` in your regex.  That is a little easier to understand ("8 digits, T, 6 digits").  After all, you'd have to further validate the input anyway, to avoid the 14th month, the 37th day of the month, or the 27th hour of the day.

Comment: It can be made shorter with `AAA_BBB_(?:AT)?CCCC_(.*)_\d{4}[01]\d[0-3]\dT[0-2]\d[0-5]\d[0-5]\d`

Comment: I added an answer.

Comment: Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add an optional group, `(?:AT)?`, before `CCCC`:

```
AAA_BBB_(?:AT)?CCCC_(.*)_[0-9]{4}[0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]T[0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9]
        ^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mx9pCx/1)

I also contracted the four `[0-9]` to `[0-9]{4}` to make the pattern shorter.

The `(?:AT)?` is a non-capturing group to which a `?` quantifier is applied. The `?` quantifier makes the whole sequence of letters match 1 or 0 times, making it optional in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Please give the following regex a try.

```
AAA_BBB_(ATCCCC|CCCC)_(.*)_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]T[0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9].
```

It would only match ATCCCC or CCCC. It won't be able to support dynamic characters preceding CCCC. You would need to use wildcards for that.

Also, you would need to change your `matcher.group(1)` statement to `matcher.group(2)`

Comment: Thank you for your tip. However, I didnt want to change the code and hence the ask.