# Find file with a pattern

Tags: java, regex

I try to search file with a name like: ENV20120517 every thing you what and finish by .DAT

So i set pattern to: "ENV20120517*.*DAT".

```
 public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    if (pattern != null) {
        return name.matches(pattern);
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Why with the previous pattern,  i get true for: name =  "ENV20120516053518.DAT" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) takes a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), and not a [glob pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29).

It so happens that `ENV20120517*.*DAT` is a valid regex. It does, however, have a different meaning to what you're expecting: it matches any string that starts with `ENV2012051` and ends in `DAT` (the `.*` matches anything, and the `7*` is effectively a no-op).

The following regex is equivalent to the pattern in your question `ENV20120517.*[.].*DAT`

For some ideas on how to do glob matching in Java, see [Is there an equivalent of java.util.regex for "glob" type patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247772/is-there-an-equivalent-of-java-util-regex-for-glob-type-patterns)

Comment: `DAT` must be at the end: Java's `matches(...)` validates the entire input string.

Comment: This answer might help a lot of people that are not aware of the functionality of `String.matches()`. +1

Comment: with pattern = ENV20120517 and name.startsWith(pattern) && name.endsWith("DAT"); that work fine... but is there a better way to resolve the problem?

Comment: @robert: The pattern `ENV20120517.*.DAT` would be the equivalent to the glob pattern `ENV20120517*.DAT`.

Comment: don't forget to escape the second '.' in the regex

Answer (score 0):

The parttern should be `"ENV20120517.*DAT"`, because `"ENV20120517*.*DAT"`, the first `*` matches 0 or more 7 char, so`"ENV20120516053518.DAT".matches("ENV20120517*.*DAT")` is true.

Comment: if i put: ENV20120517.*DAT, there are no file found

Comment: you run: String pattern = "ENV20120517.*DAT";
  for (int i = 100000; i < 1000000; i++) {
   String fileName = "ENV20120517" + i + ".DAT";
   if (!fileName.matches(pattern)) {
    System.out.println(fileName + " doesn't match pattern: "
      + pattern);
   }
  }

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pattern = "ENV20120517.*\\.DAT"
```

Or more strictly:

```
pattern = "^ENV20120517.*\\.DAT$"
```