# Regex formula for filtering JTable's single column

Tags: java, regex

I have a JTable with 4 columns (name, category, duration, file size) and JTextField in which I enter phrases to find specific records in that JTable.

I'd need a Regex formula, which'd filter the records in this way:

JTable:

name | category | duration | file size

Linkin.Park | cat1 | 00:03:30 | 5,30

If I enter phrase: *kin* - it will show all songs which have "kin" inside the name.

If I enter phrase: lin*ar* - it will show all songs which start with "lin", then have any amount of characters, then have "ar" and then any amount of characters.

If I enter phrase: lin?in* - it will show all songs wich start with "lin", then have 1 character, then have "in" and then any amount of characters.

Also, I need that filter to only consider the first column of the JTable (name), for example, writing: 30* will show songs wich start with 30, but not those which don't start with it but have the duration for example 3:30 or file size for example 7,30.

I'm sorry for my english xD.

I have this kind of search right now:

```
    private void search(String text) {
            TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(tableUtwory.getModel());
            tableUtwory.setRowSorter(sorter);
            String regex;
            if(text.startsWith("*") && text.endsWith("*")) {
                    String s = Pattern.quote(text.replaceAll("^\\*|\\*$", ""));
                    regex = "(?i).+" + s + ".+";
            } else if(text.startsWith("*")) {
                    String s = Pattern.quote(text.replaceAll("^\\*", ""));
                    regex = "(?i).+" + s + "$";
            } else if(text.endsWith("*")) {
                    String s = Pattern.quote(text.replaceAll("\\*$", ""));
                    regex = "(?i)^" + s + ".+";
            } else {
                    String s = Pattern.quote(text);
                    regex = "(?i)^" + s + "$";
            }
    sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(regex));
    sorter.setSortKeys(null);
}
```

But it doesn't return any result if I insert "*" between characters (for example lin*ar*), and I don't have the option to use "?". Also, as for now it also considers other columns, not only name column, so if I enter "30*" it returns also songs which size or duration have 30.

Comment: Sounds like you want wildcard matching. See this question for some ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247772/is-there-an-equivalent-of-java-util-regex-for-glob-type-patterns. I should add that if you want more specific help, you should be more specific about your problem. A [minimal working example](http://www.sscce.org/) would be nice.

Comment: I don't see any try of yours to accomplish this task. This is not a site to say "I want this and that, and with that" ... We have to see your effort ...

Answer (score 0):

The second part of your question:

You have to only go through the first column of the dataValues (or whatever you called it) two dimension array, like:

```
for (int i=0; i<=dataValues.length; i++) {
  String s = dataValues[i][0];
}
```

Anyway, could you provide more information about your JTable, especially the data model?

For the first part:
The easiest way is to read the JTextField into a regex, but you have to make sure, that it only contains * and/or ? as regex characters then try to match it up with the String s value above. And you have to transform the ? to .{1} and the * to .*

If not you are the one setting the datavalues for the JTable, then you can get them directly from the JTable...

```
public static Object[][] getTableData(JTable table) {
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
int nRow = dtm.getRowCount(), nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();
Object[][] tableData = new Object[nRow][nCol];
for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++)
    for (int j = 0 ; j < nCol ; j++)
        tableData[i][j] = dtm.getValueAt(i,j);
return tableData;
}

Object[][] dataValues = getTableData(YourJTable);

String regex;
if (s.indexOf("*") != -1) {
  regex = s.replaceAll("*", ".*");
}
if (regex.indexOf("?") != -1) {
  regex = regex.replaceAll("?", ".{1}");
}
for (int i=0; i<=dataValues.length; i++) {
      String s2 = (String) dataValues[i][0];
      if (s2.matches(regex)) {
         System.out.println("Match: " + s2);
      } else {
         System.out.println("Not match: " + s2); //for debugging
      }
}
```

}

Note that, if someone writes any special characters or combination for regex in the JTextField, then it messes up everything... so you have to care of the proper input.