# Match path string using glob in Java

Tags: java, glob

I have following string as a glob rule:

```
**/*.txt
```

And test data:

```
/foo/bar.txt
/foo/buz.jpg
/foo/oof/text.txt
```

Is it possible to use glob rule (without converting glob to regex) to match test data and return valud entries ?

One requirement: `Java 1.6`

Comment: In pure Java, or would you be willing to look at third party implementations?

Comment: I preffer pure Java. However 3rd party libs also can be acceptable.

Comment: You might be able to hack [`FileSystem.getPathMatcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher(java.lang.String)) to your needs.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks. However it's available since Java 1.7 - I didn't mentioned about it - I have to compile it with Java 1.6

Comment: It is not available in 1.6 (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247772/is-there-an-equivalent-of-java-util-regex-for-glob-type-patterns). Why do you prohibit yourself to use the 'glob-to-regex' technique ? You can also use the [wildcard](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/wildcard) library

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have Java 7 can use [`FileSystem.getPathMatcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher%28java.lang.String%29):

```
final PathMatcher matcher = FileSystem.getPathMatcher("glob:**/*.txt");
```

This will require converting your strings into instances of `Path`:

```
final Path myPath = Paths.get("/foo/bar.txt");
```

For earlier versions of Java you might get some mileage out of Apache Commons' [`WildcardFileFilter`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/WildcardFileFilter.html). You could also try and steal some code from Spring's [`AntPathMatcher`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.java) - that's very close to the glob-to-regex approach though.

Comment: Sadly I have to compile jar with 1.6

Answer (score 4):

[`FileSystem#getPathMatcher(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher-java.lang.String-) is an abstract method, you cannot use it directly. You need to do get a FileSystem instance first, e.g. the default one:

```
PathMatcher m = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:**/*.txt");
```

Some examples:

```
// file path
PathMatcher m = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:**/*.txt");
m.matches(Paths.get("/foo/bar.txt"));                // true
m.matches(Paths.get("/foo/bar.txt").getFileName());  // false

// file name only
PathMatcher n = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:*.txt");
n.matches(Paths.get("/foo/bar.txt"));                // false
n.matches(Paths.get("/foo/bar.txt").getFileName());  // true
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to the previous answer: `org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.wildcardMatch(filename, wildcardMatcher)`
from Apache `commons-lang` library.