# How to match pattern and display files

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

From my eclipse plugin i ask the user to enter a pattern, based on that i show the list of files that match the pattern. Ex user can enter some thing like this: *DAO or *DAO* etc.

How should i validated this pattern and match the file names in my code.

Comment: what do you need exactly? I do not understand your example. what have you tried?

Comment: The answer to your question depends on the requirements, which you did not provide.

Comment: there is a dialog box, where user can select a folder and enter a pattern. I need to list out all the files from that folder that match the pattern. For ex: if user wants the list of files whose name ends with DAO, they will give *DAO in the pattern text box.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29). According to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24677807), you could try [`FileSystem.getPathMatcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java [`FilenameFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) to filter files in a directory by any criteria you'd like:

```
File dir = new File(dirName);
FilenameFilter filenameFilter = new <your filter implementation>
File[] files = dir.listFiles(filenameFilter);
```

[Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/package-summary.html) library has several useful implementation for this (by name, by pattern, by wildcard...).