# Java: Possible to name a path with exactly 1 unknown directory?

Tags: java

Lets say I have a directory-structure.

```
/a/b/c/<unknown name>/d/e/f/<files>
```

for Windows:

```
C:\a\b\c\<unknown name>\d\e\f<files>
```

I know a/b/c is always there and also d/e/f/.

I do not know the directory () between them but I know there is only 1.

Is there a way in Java I can name this path without finding out the name of the 1 unknown directory to access ??

Like so?

```
/a/b/c/*/d/e/f
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?  Your goal is *very* unclear.

Comment: Particularly what you mean by "name this path"

Comment: Why can't you create a Path or File object from directory c, list files to find the unknown directory name, and then proceed on down

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible but probably not as straightforward as you think, you'd use the [`Files.walk`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) method like follows:

```
    Path root = Paths.get("S:\\Coding\\");

    String prefix = "A\\AB";
    String suffix = "B\\C";
    
    Path searchRoot = root.resolve(prefix);
    
    System.err.println(searchRoot);
    
    List<Path> paths = Files.walk(searchRoot).filter(f -> f.endsWith(suffix)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    paths.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Outputs:

```
stderr: S:\Coding\A\AB
stdout: S:\Coding\A\AB\ZZZ\B\C
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a dockerized app based on a linux distribution.

You can run this unix command: `find . -name d/e/f/yourFilename` using [Process Builder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

This will return the complete filepath to your file which will include the unknown portion. And then you can assign it to a String and use in your Java app.

Answer (score 0):

You can hardcode your search method as indicated in other answers. Or, to stay flexible match against patterns. You would need some pattern language to specify your path:

- Shells typically use [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).
- Alternatively you could use regexp to distinguish wanted from unwanted files.

Once you have such a pattern matcher, use a tree walking algorithm (traverse the directory structure recursively), match each absolute path name with your pattern. If it matches, perform some action.

Be aware some globbing seems to exist in Java - see [Match path string using glob in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677662/match-path-string-using-glob-in-java#24677807)