# Is there any built-in way to convert glob to regex in scala?

Tags: regex, scala, glob

I am trying to implement a simple text search that supports glob patterns. Is there any built-in way to do it?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247772/is-there-an-equivalent-of-java-util-regex-for-glob-type-patterns

Comment: yeah I was there.. I do not want to use FileSystem.getPathMatcher(String) as I don't have a path. As that thread does not contain any other built-in ways, I thought there may be a better solution now in 2016 than copy that java code and convert it to scala

Comment: Java versions here, pretty simple to convert to Scala; http://stackoverflow.com/a/17369948/21755