# Java string matching with wildcards

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, wildcard

I have a pattern string with a wild card say X (E.g.: abc*).

Also I have a set of strings which I have to match against the given pattern.

E.g.:

abf - false

abc_fgh - true

abcgafa - true

fgabcafa - false

I tried using regex for the same, it didn't work.

Here is my code

```
String pattern = "abc*";
String str = "abcdef";

Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern);

return regex.matcher(str).matches();
```

This returns false

Is there any other way to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your code. What are all the wild cards you want to support?

Comment: Why didn't the regex work? What did you try?

Comment: show us what you tried - maybe a simple fix

Comment: you mean `abc.+` ?

Comment: why not just use `String.contains` ?

Comment: That should be easy to do with regex, just replace the wildcards with the appropriate expression (e.g. `.*` for `*` and `.` for `?`) and use `String#matches()`.

Comment: @ScaryWombat `fgabcafa` should _not_ match but it would with `"fgabcafa".contains("abc")`

Comment: @Thomas that is not working but he can use the `String::startsWith` method. But the best is to use regexps.

Comment: @Thomas Oh sorry, I was reading the OP's question as that were his results, not what he was wanting - in that case `startsWith`

Comment: @Sunflame why shouldn't that be working if he's using the _correct_ regex? Assuming the wildcards can be anywhere (and probably multiple wildcards as well) you can't just use `startsWith()`, `contains()` or `endsWith()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use bash style pattern to Java style pattern converter:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String patternString = createRegexFromGlob("abc*");
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("abf", "abc_fgh", "abcgafa", "fgabcafa");
        list.forEach(it -> System.out.println(it.matches(patternString)));
}

private static String createRegexFromGlob(String glob) {
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder("^");
    for(int i = 0; i < glob.length(); ++i) {
        final char c = glob.charAt(i);
        switch(c) {
            case '*': out.append(".*"); break;
            case '?': out.append('.'); break;
            case '.': out.append("\\."); break;
            case '\\': out.append("\\\\"); break;
            default: out.append(c);
        }
    }
    out.append('$');
    return out.toString();
}
```

[Is there an equivalent of java.util.regex for “glob” type patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247772/is-there-an-equivalent-of-java-util-regex-for-glob-type-patterns)
[Convert wildcard to a regex expression](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0515.html)

Comment: Note that `String#matches()` doesn't require the expression to be wrapped in `^...$` since that's done implicitly anyways.

Comment: @Thomas - noted.. pattern matching works without ^...$ wrapper also

Answer (score 2):

you can use stringVariable.startsWith("abc")

Comment: that won't work... the input pattern provided is abc*, and basically, it could be anything like *.sh, abc*, I'm looking for linux style pattern matching

Answer (score 1):

`abc*` would be the RegEx that matches `ab`, `abc`, `abcc`, `abccc` and so on.
What you want is `abc.*` - if `abc` is supposed to be the beginning of the matched string and it's optional if anything follows it.
Otherwise you could prepend `.*` to also match strings with `abc` in the middle: `.*abc.*`

Generally i recommend playing around with a site like [this](http://regexr.com/) to learn RegEx. You are asking for a pretty basic pattern but it's hard to say what you need exactly. Good Luck!

EDIT:
It seems like you want the user to type a part of a file name (or so) and you want to offer something like a search functionality (you could have made that clear in your question IMO). In this case you could bake your own RegEx from the users' input:

```
private Pattern getSearchRegEx(String userInput){
    return Pattern.compile(".*" + userInput + ".*");
}
```

Of course that's just a very simple example. You could modify this and then use the RegEx to match file names.

Comment: Thanks.. but what I really want is linux style file matching like 
E.g: ls *.sh will give all files ending with .sh or ls abc* will give files starting with abc... I don't have control over the pattern or the actual strings...

Comment: Why don't you have control over the pattern? Does a user input the pattern?

Comment: yes.. user give the pattern input.. and strings are a list of file names which I have to match

Answer (score 0):

So I thin here is your answer: 
The regexp that you are looking for is this : `[a][b][c].*`

Here is my code that works:

```
    String first = "abc"; // true
    String second = "abctest"; // true
    String third = "sthabcsth"; // false

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a][b][c].*");

    System.out.println(first.matches(pattern.pattern())); // true
    System.out.println(second.matches(pattern.pattern())); // true
    System.out.println(third.matches(pattern.pattern())); // false
```

But if you want to check only if starts with or ends with you can use the methods of `String`: `.startsWith()` and `endsWith()`

Comment: `[a][b][c].*` doesn't make sense. You are creating character classes with only one character in them. It's the same as `abc.*`

Comment: Yes you are right, I was checking with the IntelliJ built in Regexp check, and Idk why it didn't work with abc.*.

Answer (score 0):

```java
  // The main function that checks if two given strings match. The pattern string  may contain
  // wildcard characters
  default boolean matchPattern(String pattern, String str) {

    // If we reach at the end of both strings, we are done
    if (pattern.length() == 0 && str.length() == 0) return true;

    // Make sure that the characters after '*' are present in str string. This function assumes that
    // the pattern string will not contain two consecutive '*'
    if (pattern.length() > 1 && pattern.charAt(0) == '*' && str.length() == 0) return false;

    // If the pattern string contains '?', or current characters of both strings match
    if ((pattern.length() > 1 && pattern.charAt(0) == '?')
        || (pattern.length() != 0 && str.length() != 0 && pattern.charAt(0) == str.charAt(0)))
      return matchPattern(pattern.substring(1), str.substring(1));

    // If there is *, then there are two possibilities
    // a: We consider current character of str string
    // b: We ignore current character of str string.
    if (pattern.length() > 0 && pattern.charAt(0) == '*')
      return matchPattern(pattern.substring(1), str) || matchPattern(pattern, str.substring(1));
    return false;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("w*ks", "weeks"); // Yes
    test("we?k*", "weekend"); // Yes
    test("g*k", "gee"); // No because 'k' is not in second
    test("*pqrs", "pqrst"); // No because 't' is not in first
    test("abc*bcd", "abcdhghgbcd"); // Yes
    test("abc*c?d", "abcd"); // No because second must have 2 instances of 'c'
    test("*c*d", "abcd"); // Yes
    test("*?c*d", "abcd"); // Yes
  }
```