# Searching string with wildcards

Tags: java, regex, string

I am doing the following programming exercise: [String searching with wildcard](https://www.codewars.com/kata/546c7f89bed2e12fb300056f). The statement is:

> The method below, is the most simple string search algorithm. It will
>   find the first occurrence of a word in a text string.
>
> haystack = the whole text
>
> needle = searchword
>
> wildcard = _
>
> find("strike", "i will strike down upon thee"); // return 7
>
> The find method is already made.
>
> The problem is to implement wildcard(s) in the needle. If you have a _
>   in the needle it will match any character in the haystack.
>
> A normal string search algorithm will find the first occurrence of a
>   word(needle) in a text(haystack), starting on index 0. Like this:
>
> find("strike", "I will strike down upon thee"); return 7
>
> A wildcard in the needle will match any character in the haystack. The
>   method should work on any types of needle, and haystasks. You can
>   assume the needle is shorter than(or equal to) the haystack.
>
> find("g__d", "That's the good thing about being president"); // return
>   11
>
> If no match the method should return -1

We have written the following code:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class SearchEngine {
    static int find(String needle, String haystack){
      System.out.println("needle: "+needle);
      System.out.println("haystack: "+haystack);
      String regex = needle.replace("_",".");
      if(regex.equals(needle)){
        return haystack.indexOf(needle);
      }
      System.out.println("regex: "+regex);
      Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(haystack);
      int pos = -1;
      if(m.find()){
        pos = m.start();
      }
      System.out.println("pos: "+pos);
      return pos;
    }
}
```

We have found a curious test where it does not pass.Being the test cases:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class WildsTest {
    String haystack = "Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary";    
    @Test
    public void normalSearchTest(){
        assertEquals(0,SearchEngine.find("Once", haystack));
        assertEquals(12, SearchEngine.find("midnight", haystack));
        assertEquals(-1, SearchEngine.find("codewars", haystack));
    }
    @Test
    public void wildSearchTest(){
        assertEquals(5, SearchEngine.find("_po_", haystack));
        assertEquals(12, SearchEngine.find("___night", haystack));
        assertEquals(3, SearchEngine.find("___4$&%$--___", "-..,.44$&%$--,.,"));
    }
 }
```

It fails in the last case:

```
needle: ___4$&%$--___
haystack: -..,.44$&%$--,.,
regex: ...4$&%$--...
pos: -1
```

Why is the reason that the regex does not match "...4$&%$--..." inside "-..,.44$&%$--,.,"?

We have also read:

- [Can Java String.indexOf() handle a regular expression as a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194310/can-java-string-indexof-handle-a-regular-expression-as-a-parameter)
- https://howtodoinjava.com/regex/match-any-set-of-characters/
- [Wildcard matching in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337657/wildcard-matching-in-java)
- [Java string matching with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45321050/java-string-matching-with-wildcards)

EDIT:

We have followed @Alex suggestion, and tried to use Pattern.quote:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class SearchEngine {
    static int find /**/ (String needle, String haystack){
      System.out.println("needle: "+needle);
      System.out.println("haystack: "+haystack);
      String regex = needle.replace("_",".");
      if(regex.equals(needle)){
        return haystack.indexOf(needle);
      }
      System.out.println("regex: "+regex);
      String quotedRegex = Pattern.quote(regex);
      System.out.println("quotedRegex: "+quotedRegex);
      Matcher m = Pattern.compile(quotedRegex).matcher(haystack);
      int pos = -1;
      if(m.find()){
        pos = m.start();
      }
      System.out.println("pos: "+pos);
      return pos;
    }
}
```

However we have found the following trace:

```
needle: _po_
haystack: Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary
regex: .po.
quotedRegex: \Q.po.\E
pos: -1
expected:<5> but was:<-1>
```

How could we use Pattern.quote to achieve searching with wildcards?

In addition we have followed @s.fuhrm suggestion and replaced the characters with special meaning, in this case the $, with "\\$"

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class SearchEngine {
    static int find /**/ (String needle, String haystack){
      System.out.println("needle: "+needle);
      System.out.println("haystack: "+haystack);
      String regex = needle.replace("_",".");
      if(regex.equals(needle)){
        return haystack.indexOf(needle);
      }
      System.out.println("regex: "+regex);

      Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex.replace("$","\\$")).matcher(haystack);
      int pos = -1;
      if(m.find()){
        pos = m.start();
      }
      System.out.println("pos: "+pos);
      return pos;
    }
}
```

Being this the code which passes the tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the reason that the regex does not match "...4$&%$--..." inside
>   "-..,.44$&%$--,.,"?

At least `$` is a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) matching at the end of line. This is not what you're wanting. you need to replace `$` with `\$` respectively `"\\$"`

Answer (score 2):

There are characters in your 'needle' which have special meaning in regex, namely a dollar sign $ which means 'end of line' in regex. You should escape such special characters when making a regex in order to march a literal string. You can use Pattern.quote method to do this.