# list matching in groovy switch statement

Tags: groovy

Is there a way to achieve something like this in `groovy`?

```
def list1 = ['trs', 'file.xlsx', 'xxx']
def list2 = ['rls', 'file.xml', 'yyy']

def switchCheck(list) {
    switch (list) {
        case ['trs',  /* matches pattern *.xlsx */ , /* any value */]:
            println "trs message"
            break
        case ['rls', /* matches pattern *.xml */ , /* any value */]:
            println "rls message"
            break
        default: 
            println "no match"
            break
    }
}

switchCheck(list1)
switchCheck(list2)
```

I want to check list data in the switch statement where some of its fields do not matter, while others should match a certain pattern (like ends with `*.xlsx` or `.xml`)

Comment: Check [this](http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2009/09/groovy-goodness-using-regular.html) for regex, and [this](http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2009/08/groovy-goodness-switch-statement.html) for list.

Comment: @Rao: Actually it is not regex , it is glob pattern.

Comment: so basically I need something like `['trs', ~/match extension/, ~/match any/]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just create a demonstration example because monkey patch is evil.
You can modify [`isCase`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.3.5/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#isCase(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object)) at runtime.

`isCase` is the method, when groovy calls in switch statement.(Different from Java)

Just call like this:

```
    ... // You don't need to modify switchCheck method.
    def list2 = ['rls', 'file.xml', 'yyy']
List.metaClass.isCase = { Object switchValue ->
    if (!switchValue in List && switchValue.size() == 3) {
        false
    } else {
        switchValue.first() == delegate.first() && (switchValue[1]) in ~(createRegexFromGlob(delegate[1]))
    }

}
switchCheck(list1)
```

The createRegexFromGlob is copied from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1248627/4680436).

Comment: I have no problem using raw regex instead of glob. I just want a fancy one-liner for `list` case

Comment: Then just use `~(delegate[1])` instead of  `~(createRegexFromGlob(delegate[1]))`

Comment: so there is no way for `['trs', ~/xlsx/, ~/*/]` something?

Comment: @user1432980 If you use the orgin version `isCase` it always calls `contains` semantics.

Comment: I see. So it only works for standalone regex in `case` statement?

Comment: @user1432980 You can always modify the `isCase` to meet your own needs. The bad thing about monkey patch is that may lead to unwanted behavior, If other parts of code use `isCase`.

Comment: I see. Well too bad.