# What is the regular expression that Bash uses to match file names?

Tags: regex, bash, pattern-matching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create regex from glob expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445910/create-regex-from-glob-expression)

We know that Bash doesn't use regular expressions for matching file names. For example:
`*.dat` would match all file names with the dat extension. However, the same pattern in regular expression form would have been: `.*\.dat`

My question is how can I take a Bash-style pattern and translate it into a valid regular expression that would match the same file names.

For simplicity sake, let's ignore all sorts of Bash expansions and let's assume that Bash does **not** treat . .. and / separately.

Comment: What kind of regular expression do you want to convert it to?

Comment: If anything, the bash version is closer to a "true" regular expression over ASCII \ {'*'} than is what you provide as the "real" thing (perl?).

Answer (score 0):

I think that should not be too complicated. The non-special characters can simply be left as they are.

The special symbols may have to be translated to "usual" regular expressions.

Exemplary, if we consider `*.dat`, we have to convert the `*` into `.*` and the `.` to `\.`. Moreover we have to change `?` (match one character) to `.`. Character groups `[abc]` should essentially stay the same, probably adjusting some special symbols. And you'll have to recognize escaped characters, e.g. `\*` and treat them adequate (in case of `\*`, just leave it there).

So, all you have to do is create a list of special symbols and their corresponding equivalents in usual regular expressions.

However, you should definitely have a look at the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445910/create-regex-from-glob-expression) provided by @WoLpH.