# How to convert between a glob pattern and a regexp pattern in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, glob

Glob patterns are similar to regexp patterns but not identical. Given a glob string, how to I convert it into the corresponding regexp string?

See [Dir#glob](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob) and Perl's [Text-Glob](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/Text-Glob/Text/Glob.pm.html) library, and [Create regex from glob expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445910/create-regex-from-glob-expression) (for python).

Answer (score 2):

I've written a partial implementation of this as part of the [rerun](http://github.com/alexch/rerun) gem but if anyone knows a better way, I'd love to hear about it. Here's my code (latest [code](https://github.com/alexch/rerun/blob/master/lib/rerun/glob.rb) and [tests](https://github.com/alexch/rerun/blob/master/spec/glob_spec.rb) are up on github).

```
class Glob
  NO_LEADING_DOT = '(?=[^\.])'   # todo

  def initialize glob_string
    @glob_string = glob_string
  end

  def to_regexp_string
    chars = @glob_string.split('')
    in_curlies = 0;
    escaping = false;
    chars.map do |char|
      if escaping
        escaping = false
        char
      else
        case char
          when '*'
            ".*"
          when "?"
            "."
          when "."
            "\\."

          when "{"
            in_curlies += 1
            "("
          when "}"
            if in_curlies > 0
              in_curlies -= 1
              ")"
            else
              char
            end
          when ","
            if in_curlies > 0
              "|"
            else
              char
            end
          when "\\"
            escaping = true
            "\\"

          else
            char

        end
      end
    end.join
  end
end
```

Comment: Cool. One minor improvement is to map `{` to `(?:`, since you don't really need to capture it.