# Extended regular expressions (ERE) for .gitignore

Tags: regex, git, gitignore, metacharacters

Is there a way to use extended regular expressions(ERE) in a `.gitignore` file? For example I want to use the `+` repetition character in a `.gitignore` file. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1470664/6309) and detailed in "[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2902126/6309)", the function [fnmatch()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fnmatch.html) is involved to interpret glob patterns, which means regular expressions are not supported.

This is what [`gitignore` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) mentions:

> Otherwise, `git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for consumption by fnmatch(3)` with the `FNM_PATHNAME` flag: wildcards in the pattern will not match a `/` in the pathname.
>   For example, "`Documentation/*.html`" matches "`Documentation/git.html`" but not "`Documentation/ppc/ppc.html`" or "`tools/perf/Documentation/perf.html`".

You can see some correspondence between glob patterns and regular expressions in [those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247772/is-there-an-equivalent-of-java-util-regex-for-glob-type-patterns) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445910/create-regex-from-glob-expression).

Answer (score 13):

The `.gitignore` (and other) files use filename globs, not regular expressions.

I very much doubt you can convince the git hackers to change that: Just too ingrained by now, and globs are much more familiar as filename matchers.

Comment: That's a pity. Such a handy feature could it be.

Comment: @ArturBarseghyan, consider Mercurial, it has that neat feature and many other cool features too.

Comment: @modchan: I know it exists in Mercurial and I use it a lot. Thanks for the comment anyway.

Comment: Has someone tried submitting a patch? Who knows, perhaps the git hackers would also find this useful.