# Ignore the same directory structure on multiples path with .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore, smartgit

I have a website linked to Git repository at Bitbucket. This site is multi language but I need to upload to repository only `spanish` and `english` languages. The problem here is that same structure is present on several paths. See the example below (the same language structure is repeated on multiples paths):

```
system\
    cms\
    language\
        arabic\
        brazilian\
        chinese_simplified\
        chinese_traditional\
        czech\
        danish\
        dutch\
        english\
        finnish\
        french\
        german\
        greek\
        hebrew\
        hungarian\
        indonesian\
        italian\
        khmer\
        lithuanian\
        persian\
        polish\
        portuguese\
        russian\
        slovenian\
        spanish\
        swedish\
        thai\
        vietnamese\
    modules\
        addons\
            language\
                arabic\
                brazilian\
                chinese_simplified\
                chinese_traditional\
                czech\
                danish\
                dutch\
                english\
                finnish\
                french\
                german\
                greek\
                hebrew\
                hungarian\
                indonesian\
                italian\
                khmer\
                lithuanian\
                persian\
                polish\
                portuguese\
                russian\
                slovenian\
                spanish\
                swedish\
                thai\
                vietnamese\
        blog\
            language\
                ...
        comments\
            language\
                ...
        contact\
            language\
                ...
        files\
            language\
                ...
        keywords\
            language\
                ...
        maintenance\
            language\
                ...
        navigation\
            language\
                ...
        pages\
            language\
                ...
        permissions\
            language\
                ...
        redirects\
            language\
                ...
        search\
            language\
                ...
        settings\
            language\
                ...
        sitemap\
            language\
                ...
        streams_core\
            language\
                ...
        templates\
            language\
                ...
        users\
            language\
                ...
        variables\
            language\
                ...
        widgets\
            language\
                ...
        wysiwyg\
            language\
                ...
```

Is there any way, or regex if it's supported on `.gitignore` to allow only `spanish` and `english` and ommit the rest of them?

**Edit: toydarian solution**
Following @toydarian suggestion I added this lines to `.gitignore` file:

```
language/arabic/*
language/brazilian/*
language/chinese_simplified/*
language/chinese_traditional/*
language/czech/*
language/danish/*
language/dutch/*
language/finnish/*
language/french/*
language/german/*
language/greek/*
language/hebrew/*
language/hungarian/*
language/indonesian/*
language/italian/*
language/khmer/*
language/lithuanian/*
language/persian/*
language/polish/*
language/portuguese/*
language/russian/*
language/slovenian/*
language/swedish/*
language/thai/*
language/vietnamese/*
```

But as image shows, it's not working, any other advice or way?

[image]

Comment: I think you should be able to add `language/` on line 1 to ignore all language directories, then afterward add `!english/` and `!spanish/` on the subsequent 2 lines... try it out first before I officially answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wildcards as you can use in the shell. [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672613/extended-regular-expressions-ere-for-gitignore)
Regular expressions are not supported.

So the only thing is to add `<language>/*` for every language, you want to exclude to your `.gitignore`
That will exclude every sub-directory of `<language>`

`<language>` is a placeholder for a specific language like "german"

Comment: So, if I understand I'll need to add several lines as `system/cms/language/german`, `system/cms/language/french`, `system/cms/language/italian` and so on?

Comment: no, you need exactly one line for every language looking like this: `<language>/*`. e.g. `german/*`, `thai/*` and `polish/*`

Comment: Well I did this: `system/cms/language/*
!system/cms/language/english
!system/cms/language/spanish` but doesn't work I'm still seeing all the languages, is that wrong? I mean I exclude every but spanish and english

Comment: As I said, you can use any wildcards, you can use in the bash. so excluding with `!path/to/dir` does not work. See my comment five minutes ago. That's the only way, I can see.

Comment: Well, `.gitignore` does not work on files, you already added to the repository...

Comment: Yes, it was added before but now I want to delete them from the repository and leave out, is that possible?

Comment: yes, you can delete files from a git repository with the `git rm` command. That will delete them from the file system, though.