# How to git ignore file with same name as container directory?

Tags: git, gitignore

The file named as "project" is resultant of a build which produces a binary file with the same name as the container directory:

```
project/
    src/
    main.c
    project <-- binary file, same name as container directory
```

Being more general, how to ignore a file that have the same name as their container directory? Keep in mind that if "project" directory is renamed the resultant built file will change name too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a path starting with the root git directory in `.gitignore`. So for your example, you could put

```
/project/project
```

in your `.gitignore`. I'm not sure if there's a way in git to see the repository name and ignore same-names files, but since it seems like you're using a script (or makefile or whatever) to build what you're keeping in the repository, you should be able to write to `.gitignore` from that script. Something like

```
echo $projName"/"$projName > .gitignore
```

would work. You'd need to specify the location of `.gitignore`, depending on where your makefile/script is located.

Answer (score 4):

To match files with the same name as their containing directory you'd need a language more powerful than the shell globs that .gitignore uses, like regular expressions with backreferences.

The question of how to use regular expressions in .gitignore has been asked before ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15672613/2404501)) and the answer has always been "You can't."

Get used to the idea that you have to update your .gitignore when you rename a directory.

Comment: Oh, that's  a shame :( a simple `/(\w+)/\1` would solve the issue if regexp were allowed.