# In Git, how to ignore all files whose name ends with `.foo.XXXX` where XXXX is any "normal" file name extension?

Tags: regex, git, gitignore, glob

Putting

```
syntax:regexp
*.foo.[a-z]{1,4}
```

in `.gitignore` does not work.  I remember seeing

```
syntax:glob
```

and

```
syntax:regexp
```

some time ago in some `.gitignore` files, but I couldn't file such syntax in Git manual.  Is there a way to use regular regex in `.gitignore`?

Comment: You accidentally the whole files.

Comment: Could you undelete some expletives?

Comment: Your syntax looks like regex, not glob.

Comment: Using `syntax:regexp` atop does not work either.

Comment: How to **WHAT** all files?

Comment: He is playing with the fact that you forgot the main verb ("ignore" I guess) in the question title, and that this was a popular meme a few years ago.

Comment: Related: [Extended regular expressions (ERE) for .gitignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672613/extended-regular-expressions-ere-for-gitignore)

Comment: Obviously he's having too much time to be too smart.

Comment: It seems you're remembering [Mercurial's `.hgignore`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html#syntax).

Comment: You're right.  I should just un-learn all of my Mercurial knowledge.

Comment: Meme background: http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-accidentally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using any regex syntax that might or might not be supported (I don't see any evidence for it either), you could get the same behavior with four rules:

```
*.foo.[a-z]
*.foo.[a-z][a-z]
*.foo.[a-z][a-z][a-z]
*.foo.[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]
```

If you wanted to compromise slightly, you could use `*.foo.?*` (anything ending in foo, a dot, and at least one more character), or `*.foo.[a-z]*` (anything ending in foo and then an extension that starts off alphabetic).

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing [`.hgignore`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html) with [`.gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

There is no such thing as a "normal file name extension"; what you can do to start off with is to add the following:

```
**/foo.*
```

*`**/` will match `foo.*` in all directories.*

`.gitignore` uses the [shell glob syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29):

> Git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for consumption by
>   fnmatch(3) with the FNM_PATHNAME flag: wildcards in the pattern will
>   not match a / in the pathname.