# Exclude all tree except some folder using Git

Tags: git, gitignore

I have some tree structure:

```
/a  
/a/a  
/a/b
/b/
..  
/a/z  
/b  
.. (thousands of folders)  
/z
```

How can I control just /a/a and /b folders?
What exclude file should be?
The way we use now is:

```
/a/*    
/c/
..  (thousands of folders)  
/z/  
!/a/a
```

But it is very not nice looking and hard for maintenance...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do that you haven't done already?  It's not clear.  What's "not nice looking" or "hard for maintenance" about the current way?

Comment: I want my .git ignore file's size less than 1 Megabyte )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved it!

```
/*
!/a/
/a/*
!/a/a/
!/b/
```

It was thousand of lines, now it just five )))

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15676377/2295034) answer standard globbing rules are used in the `.gitignore` syntax so you can't use standard regular expressions to solve this problem.

That said, you can shorten your `gitignore` a bit. This pattern will exclude all folders other than `a` and `b`:

```
[cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]
```

Comment: Sorry, but I need also include directory /b )

Comment: @Olga It can make your `.gitignore` file a little more managable by not having to specify every folder on it's own line

Comment: mmm... thanx... it is very sad that git can not support such case... I think in our case it will  harder to handle folders on same line... because we have much .gitignore files describes similar environments, and we need sometime remove or add folders and copy lines from each to other... But thank you for help )