# Pattern Matching on every element in the vector

Tags: c++, regex, glob

I have a function which looks like this:

```
bool ExpandWildCard(vector<string>& names, vector<string>& result, string& wildcard) 
{
}
```

Here, I want to match the `wildcard` with each element in the vector `names` and if it does match, then add the element in `names` to the `result` vector.

Of course, if the wildcard is *, I could just add everything from `names` to `results`. Also I'm just trying to implement the `*` wildcard for now.

How can I do this in C++?

One way I thought of doing this was using `find()` algorithm but I am not sure I would match wildcards using that?

Comment: do you want to do full regular expression matching? see `std::regex`

Comment: This question is not too broad, it is clearly about how to do glob match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for some combination of [std::copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) and maybe [std::regex_match](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match):

```
bool ExpandWildCard(vector<string>& names, vector<string>& result, string& wildcard) {
  auto oldsize = result.size();
  std::copy_if(std::begin(names), std::end(names),
    std::back_inserter(result),
    [&](string const& name) {
      return std::regex_match(name, make_regex(wildcard));
    }
  );

  return (result.size() > oldsize);
}
```

Where make_regex would be the function you need to implement to convert your string into a `std::regex`.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are probably after in using `regex_match` as suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25120757/315052). [Elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/445994/315052) you can find code to convert a glob pattern into a regular expression.

If performance is not a concern, and you just need the functionality, you can use the shell to match the pattern for you. You can create a suitable command, pass the command through `popen()` and read the results and store them in your vector.

```
bool ExpandWildCard (const std::vector<std::string>& names,
                     std::vector<std::string>& result,
                     const std::string& wildcard)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "bash -c 'for word in ";
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); ++i) {
        if (names[i].size() > 0) oss << '"' << names[i] << '"' << ' ';
    }
    oss << "; do case \"$word\" in "
        << wildcard << ')' << " echo \"$word\" ;; *) ;; "
        << "esac ; done '";
    FILE *fp = ::popen(oss.str().c_str(), "r");
    if (fp == NULL) return false;
    char *line = 0;
    ssize_t len = 0;
    size_t n = 0;
    while ((len = ::getline(&line, &n, fp)) > 0) {
        if (line[len-1] == '\n') line[len-1] = '\0';
        result.push_back(line);
    }
    ::free(line);
    ::pclose(fp);
    return true;
}
```